# Sqlite next row acting strange Android

Tags: android, sqlite, counter

I have this query for moving in my database

```
Select data1,data2 From Table Where counter <"+somenumber+" and  order by counter DESC
```

this is for moving back, and i have same, but without desc for moving forward. The problem is that is going like this:68,69,70,7,71.
Why is doing this? it goes to seven before 71.

Comment: because `counter` column is a Text/varchar/not numeric column ?

Comment: it's true :) but why other numbers are ok?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Selvin suggested, change your *counter* column to hold `Integer` type and your `order by` will work properly.

Or use the `CAST` operator:

```
Select data1, data2 From Table
Where CAST(counter as integer) < 10
Order By CAST(counter AS INTEGER) DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

hey check the column type Text/varchar/not numeric column and one more thing query is not proper

`Select data1,data2 From Table Where condition1  and condition2 order by counter DESC`

Comment: thank you, when editing comment I deleted desc by accident, and M-WaJeEh answer is more complet so point to him :)